# How to retrieve name from dynamically created frames

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA and I'm in over my head this time...

I'm building an order form with several dynamically created frames, each of which contains one or more dynamically created comboboxes. What I eventually hope to achieve, is for every combobox to have a change event.

- When certain conditions are met, two textboxes have to appear
- The first of these textboxes needs to have a change event as well
- When certain conditions are met, a new combobox needs to be created right beneath the first combobox, with all the same values except the value of the first combobox
- If this happens, the height of the parent frame needs to be adjusted and all subsequent frames have to be lowered accordingly

I'm not expecting a full solution, but some help with the first step would be appreciated. Specifically, how do I make sure the new textboxes are created in the same frame as the combobox?

I've puzzled together some stuff from other threads, and came up with the code below. It breaks down at Set Included, apparently on the subgroup. Yet subgroup is a frame with the correct name. If I change "subgroup" into "Subgroep- " & aantalframes it does work.

```
Option Explicit 

Public Included As MSForms.textbox
Public subgroup As MSForms.frame
Public dinbegrepen As Long
Public dmaximum As Long 
Public aantalframes As Long

Public WithEvents ChkEvents As MSForms.combobox
Private Sub ChkEvents_Change()
If dmaximum > 1 Then
    Set subgroup = ConfigureProduct.Controls("Subgroep- " & aantalframes) 
    Set Included = 
ConfigureProduct.Controls("subgroup").Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "included")
With Included
    .value = dinbegrepen
    .Left = 305
    .Width = 25
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `"It breaks down"` doesn't give us much to work with. What exactly happens? do you get an error? (I suspect you do). What is the error message? Also, why do you want all of this in frames? (let alone in dynamically created frames). Using `Tabs` would probably be better option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550026/how-to-add-text-boxes-and-labels-to-a-frame-within-a-userform

Comment: Zac: sorry, I should have been more specific. There is indeed an error message. Although I get it in Dutch, in English it would probably be 'Cannot find the specified object.' The error code is -2147024809 (80070057).

Comment: As for tabs, wouldn't the problem be essentially the same? They would have to be created dynamically, and so I would need to know how to refer to them in my Class Module. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Knee Colas: thanks for the post, but I'm not sure it's the same problem. That user has one frame that isn't created dynamically. I need to know how to refer to multiple frames that are created dynamically.